# Sufficient condition to belong to a Lorentz space

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, harmonic-analysis

I am learning about the Lorentz spaces $L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

If I can bound a function $f(x)$ by  $C|x|^{-\frac{n}{p}}$ with $C>0$, *i.e.*
$$f(x)\leq C|x|^{-\frac{n}{p}}, \quad \text{for all}\ \ x\in \mathbb{R}^n,$$

- Can I conclude that $f\in L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) ?$
- How can I prove it ?

Comment: Yes. We have $C|x|^{-n/p}\in L^{(p,\infty)}.$ Hence $f\in L^{(p,\infty)}.$